# How to use custom page titles on different themes in Concrete5?

Tags: concrete5

I am using Concrete5 5.6.3.3. I have multiple themes active on the same site. The current page `<title>` uses the SiteName::PageName format across all themes. I want to use a custom titles on different themes.

For example on theme1, I would like to keep the SiteName but on Theme2, I would like to remove SiteName and use something else.

I tried adding my own title on other themes' header but it does not seem to have any effect. It keeps showing me SiteName::PageName. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a variable called `$pageTitle` before you include `header_required`.

As you can see here, that variable will be used from outside of the element if it's set:
https://github.com/concrete5/concrete5-legacy/blob/master/web/concrete/elements/header_required.php#L19